# Undefined Method für salt_masterkey for Array[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined

I have the problem that my server keeps rejecting my Requests because of the above mentioned Error.

Searched like the whole internet. I am at my end.

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me.

Here is the Code:

```
def login
@user = User.find_by_sql(['select s* from users Where identity like ?;', params[:identity]])
if (@user)
  respond_with(:salt_masterkey => @user.salt_masterkey, :privkey_user_enc => @user.privkey_user_enc, :pubkey_user => @user.pubkey_user, status: 100)
else
  respond_with(status: 101)
end
end
```

The problem should be within this line:

```
respond_with(:salt_masterkey => @user.salt_masterkey, ....
```

The database is built like this

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table(:users, id: false)  do |t|
        t.primary_key :user_id
        t.index :identity, :unique=>true
        t.string :identity
        t.string :salt_masterkey
        t.string :pubkey_user
        t.string :privkey_user_enc
        t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_by_sql returning an array and salt_masterkey method belongs to specific record. You should try @user.first.salt_masterkey